# Finding the point in a plane that has shortest distance from the origin using different norms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

This is a HW problem and I have being struggling how to start.

I have the plane $3x+2y+z-6=0$ and I'm asked to find the point in the plane that is closest to the origin when distance is measured by

1. 1-norm
2. 2-norm
3. $\infty$- norm

edit

we know that the distance from a plane to a point is giving by $d=\lvert \frac{Ax_0+By_0+Cz_0+D}{\lvert\lvert n \lvert\lvert}\lvert$
where n is the normal vector $n=(3,2,1)$ and $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(0,0,0)
$Hence $ \lvert \lvert n \lvert \lvert_1 =3+2+1=6$

so by plug in the equation we get $d=\frac{6}{6} =1$

similarly for the 2-norm $ \lvert \lvert n \lvert \lvert_2=\sqrt{14}$ and the distance $d= \frac{6}{\sqrt{14}} $

and $\infty$-norm $ \lvert \lvert n \lvert \lvert_\infty=3$ and $d=\frac{6}{3}=2$

Edit. My question is if I know the shortest distance from the origin to the plane. which are

1. using 1-norm the shortest distance is 1
2. 2-norm is $6/\sqrt{14}$
3. $\infty$-norm is 2

how to find the point (x,y,x) which is in the plane such that its distance satisfy the above values for each of the norms.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please take a look at [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/229831) and [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/229831). Please edit the post, and explain what you understand about the problem, and at what point exactly you're stuck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I tried to make my question more clear.

Comment: @A_WM: Please edit your post to show the work for how you obtained the minimum distances for each of the three norms.

Comment: @quasi I just edited it hope it clear now. This in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using $1$-norm distances . . .**

Let $P=(x,y,z)$ be an arbitrary point on the given plane.

Then we get
$$
3(|x|+|y|+|z|)
=
3|x|+3|y|+3|z|
\ge
3|x|+2|y|+|z|
\ge
3x+2y+z
=
6
$$
hence $||P||_1\ge 2$.

By inspection, for $P=(2,0,0)$ (which is on the plane), we have $||P||_1=2$, so the point $(2,0,0)$ is a point on the plane with minimum $1$-norm distance to the origin.

**Using $2$-norm distances . . .**

Let $P=(x,y,z)$ be a point on the given plane with minimum $2$-norm distance to the origin.

From the equation $3x+2y+z=6$, we get that the plane has normal vector $N=\langle{3,2,1}\rangle$.

It follows that $P$ is the point where the line through the origin with direction vector $N$ intersects the given plane.

The line can be expressed parametrically by
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
x&=3t\\[4pt]
y&=2t\\[4pt]
z&=t\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
which intersects the plane $3x+2y+z=6$ when
$$
3(3t)+2(2t)+(t)=6
$$
so $t=3/7$, hence 
$$
P=(3t,2t,t)
=
\left(
\frac{9}{7},
\frac{6}{7},
\frac{3}{7}
\right)
$$
**Using $\infty$-norm distances . . .**

Let $P=(x,y,z)$ be an arbitrary point on the given plane.

Then we get
$$
6\max(|x|,|y|,|z|)
\ge
3|x|+2|y|+|z|
\ge
3x+2y+z
=
6
$$
hence $||P||_\infty\ge 1$.

By inspection, for $P=(1,1,1)$ (which is on the plane), we have $||P||_{\infty}=1$, so the point $(1,1,1)$ is a point on the plane with minimum $\infty$-norm distance to the origin.